# Does running a bayesian model multiple times require multiple comparisons correction?

Tags: bayesian, multivariate-analysis, multiple-comparisons

I'm working with a set of data where the outcome of interest is a length 4 vector. If I instead model this as four different univariate outcomes, and run the same bayesian model four times (once for each position of the vector outcome), is it then necessary to adjust for multiple comparisons somehow?

Answer (score 1):

In principle, you have a multiple comparisons issues, whether you do these comparisons within a single model for the 4 dimensional vector (which you then use to do some comparisons separately for each of the 4 components), or whether you do the comparisons with four separate models.

Of course, one question is whether this is a concern for you and there are some that argue that you should simply not care about things like the familwise type I error rate or the the false discovery rate etc. (often with some appeal to the strong likelihood principle). However, many others will not agree with this view, particularly not if vague priors are used and effects across the components are treated as completely independent.

If you care about the inflation of false claims you make due to multiple comparisons, then within a single model it is easier to do something about the multiple comparisons that makes it unnecessary to e.g. adjust the credible intervals you report to e.g. 98.75% instead of 95% credible intervals (if you take a Bonferroni-style perspective). E.g. one could have a hierarchical model that automatically induces some shrinkage on the effects on the components that you study, which can often deal with multiple comparisons in a sensible manner (particularly with some sensible priors - e.g. the horseshoe prior or some truly informative priors based on real prior knowledge) and provide posterior credible intervals that do not need any further adjustment to have good properties (like frequentist coverage close to the nominal level).